# Application crashes during relase mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to build a app for bluetooth profiles...This app all working fine in debug mode and exucuting is ok. But in relase mode it crashes as...
"Combo_app.exe has stoped working"...
So I started capturing the dubug info during relase mode,
It crashes at

```
AppWnd = CreateDialog(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(COMBO_MAIN), NULL, AppWndProc);
```

(with green arrow...)..I coudnot able to trace the error....

here is the VCPROJ file of my application

```
<Configuration
            Name="Release|Win32"
            OutputDirectory=".\Release"
            IntermediateDirectory=".\Release"
            ConfigurationType="1"
            InheritedPropertySheets="$(VCInstallDir)VCProjectDefaults\UpgradeFromVC60.vsprops"
            UseOfMFC="0"
            ATLMinimizesCRunTimeLibraryUsage="false"
            CharacterSet="2"
            >
            <Tool
                Name="VCPreBuildEventTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCCustomBuildTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCXMLDataGeneratorTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCWebServiceProxyGeneratorTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCMIDLTool"
                PreprocessorDefinitions="NDEBUG"
                MkTypLibCompatible="true"
                SuppressStartupBanner="true"
                TargetEnvironment="1"
                TypeLibraryName=".\Release/combo_app.tlb"
                HeaderFileName=""
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCCLCompilerTool"
                Optimization="2"
                InlineFunctionExpansion="1"
                AdditionalIncludeDirectories=".;..\..;..\..\core\bluesdk\inc\sys;..\inc;..\..\core\bluesdk;..\..\core\bluesdk\inc;..\..\..\le\inc;..\..\hcitrans\abcsp\config;..\..\hcitrans\abcsp\include;..\..\hcitrans\modinit;..\..\minios\inc;..\..\minios\common;..\..\minios\stack_lib;..\..\hcitrans\module_init\TI;..\..\core\av\inc;..\..\core\handsfree\inc;..\..\core\hid\inc;c:\WMSDK\WMPSDK10\include;&quot;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include;&quot;"
                PreprocessorDefinitions="WIN32;NDEBUG;_WINDOWS;BTSTACK;USB_TRANS;SBC_OFFLOAD;_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS;_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS"
                StringPooling="true"
                RuntimeLibrary="0"
                EnableFunctionLevelLinking="true"
                PrecompiledHeaderFile=".\Release/combo_app.pch"
                AssemblerListingLocation=".\Release/"
                ObjectFile=".\Release/"
                ProgramDataBaseFileName=".\Release/"
                BrowseInformation="1"
                WarningLevel="3"
                WarnAsError="true"
                SuppressStartupBanner="true"
                DebugInformationFormat="1"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCManagedResourceCompilerTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCResourceCompilerTool"
                PreprocessorDefinitions="NDEBUG"
                Culture="1033"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCPreLinkEventTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCLinkerTool"
                AdditionalDependencies="wsock32.lib comctl32.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib winmm.lib setupapi.lib"
                OutputFile=".\Release/combo_app.exe"
                LinkIncremental="1"
                SuppressStartupBanner="true"
                AdditionalLibraryDirectories="..\..\minios\stack_lib\$(ConfigurationName)"
                IgnoreDefaultLibraryNames="libcmt.lib;libcmtd.lib;nafxcw.lib;nafxcwd.lib"
                GenerateDebugInformation="true"
                SubSystem="2"
                OptimizeReferences="2"
                LinkTimeCodeGeneration="1"
                RandomizedBaseAddress="1"
                DataExecutionPrevention="0"
                TargetMachine="1"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCALinkTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCManifestTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCXDCMakeTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCBscMakeTool"
                SuppressStartupBanner="true"
                OutputFile=".\Release/combo_app.bsc"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCFxCopTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCAppVerifierTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCPostBuildEventTool"
            />
        </Configuration>
    </Configurations>
```

Please get me out of this trouble..

Comment: Make a release build with debug information (yes, that's possible, just change the settings), then run in debugger.

Comment: do you have dependencies on dll using Debug C RunTime?

Comment: have you copied runtime DLLs into your application path?

Comment: One difference between debug and release builds is that variables are not initialised in release builds -- check if your variables are initialised before use

Comment: Thanks for the pointing..
Someone give a cigar to these guys...
I missed a DLL ...Now its working fine